# Group by in JPA

Tags: jpa

My Question is why the `GROUP BY` didn't show in the glassfish logs.
i added the following data below because someone wants to see it

```
 public List<Message> listAllMessageBySender(String currentUserID) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnit");
    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

    TypedQuery<Message> eq = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.sendBy.userId = :userid GROUP BY m.sendTo.userId", Message.class);
    eq.setParameter("userid", Integer.parseInt(currentUserID));
    List<Message> message = eq.getResultList();
    return message;
}
```

Glassfish 3.1.2.Logs

```
FINE: SELECT id, message, send_date, send_by, send_to FROM message WHERE (send_by = ?)
    bind => [50]


Data: 
User A : sendBy.userId = 50
User B : sendTo.userId = 44
User C : sendTo.userId = 43

id      send_date               send_by      send_to            message 

1   2013-03-14 14:58:46         44           50             50 send message to 44
2   2013-03-14 14:58:46         50           44             reply from 44 to 50
3   2013-03-14 17:38:52         44           50             2nd reply to 50
6   2013-03-14 18:22:10         50           44             44 reply to 50
7   2013-03-14 18:22:10         50           43             new

in the query above is i want to list all the user sent from User A. it causes duplication because there is two send_to 44. the xhtml below shows :

<ui:repeat value="#{messageController.items}" var="messageItem"> 
  <br />
  <div onclick="loadMessage()">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" >
      <p:graphicImage height="50" width="50" value="#{messageItem.sendTo.profilePicture}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

   <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width: 270px;">                                        
     <h:outputText value="#{messageItem.sendTo.registerName}"/>
     <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="float:right;">
       <h:outputText value="#{messageItem.sendDate}" >
         <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm"/>
       </h:outputText>
     </h:panelGroup>
   </h:panelGroup>

  </div>
   <p:remoteCommand name="loadMessageBean" action="#{messageController.loadMessage(messageItem.id)}" /> </ui:repeat>    


ERD 

User Table                        Message Table

user_id                            message_id
register_name                      send_date
                                   send_to     ----> referenced by user_id User Table
                                   send_by     ----> referenced by user_id User Table
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear. If you want to list all the messages sent by user 50, and user 50 has sent two messages to user 44, then obviously these two messages should be retrieved by the query. If you want to get all the distinct users whom the user 50 sent a message to, then it's possible, but printing the message date doesn't make sense, since obviously, the messages from user 50 to user 44 (for example) will have several different dates.

Comment: actually it has a user table that links to the message what i want to display is not just the message but also the user . ahm ignore the send_date for now . i will edit again the question to display the ERD

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This request doesn't make sense. `group by` is used when the select clause contains at least one aggregation function (sum, avg, min, max, etc.). And all the other columns must appear in the `group by` clause.

So for example, the following query would make sense:

```
SELECT max(m.length), sender.userId from Message m
inner join m.sendBy sender
GROUP BY sender.userId
```

It would return, for each message sender, the length of its longest message.

Tell us, with example data, what you would like your query to return.

If you want to get all the distinct users whom user A sent a message to, the query should simply be

```
select distinct m.sendTo from Message m 
where m.sendBy.userId = :userid
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it will logically work but i get an error 
The class 'biz.dtit.golf.entities.User' does not have the property 'sendTo'.
it's because i think i can no longer get the reference value from the user table...

i was thinking of manually remove duplicates by using this ... 
Map<Integer, Message> map = new HashMap<Integer, Message>();
        for(Message mess: message){
            if(!map.containsKey(mess.getSendTo().getUserId())){
                map.put(mess.getSendTo().getUserId(), mess);
            }
        }

Comment: Tha above query returns User instances. Not Message instances. Isn't it what you want?